# Standard to take source of software

Tags: standards

In my office we worked with a software developer that he create some software for us and now he want to quit. We need to take the source of these softwares and deliver that to another developer . Is there a standard for doing this or something like checklist for this?

Comment: Better you first hire new developer and let him work with your old developer at least for a month so new developer can get pure knowledge. then you can allow to leave job to your old/current developer.

Comment: Ali, are you a QA agent of some kind? Or is this general programming. There's a lot of programmers here, but questions about dealing with programmers without a QA slant are going to be best suited to another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Let them meet (or do an online call) and do a handover:

- Explain internals
- Installation documentation
- Build documentation
- Deploy documentation

The most important thing is that it should be complete and the new developer should be able to build it without to much hassle.

Also I suggest you place the actual code in some sort of version control systems if it is not already. If the new developer needs to access the code over the internet have them store it in https://bitbucket.org/ or https://github.com/

Comment: As @Helping Hands said in comment, this would be much easier done if original developer is still employed. If he already left, company needs to hire him as a consultant and pay him.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is:

> We need to take the **source** of these softwares and deliver that to another developer . Is there a standard for doing this or something like checklist for this?

I would say the **standard** way is that source (and with source I mean "real" source code, documentation, tests, ...) code is stored in a version controll system like *GIT*, *SVN*, *Synergie*, ..., and is "delivered" to another developer by just giving him access to this the repository.

This way you don't get in trouble to deliver the **source** even if the old developer has already left the company.

But this obviously doesn't hand over knowledge about the product. For this you need to do a handover like Niels already mentioned.